# How to stop Django 3.0 leaking db connections?

Tags: django, gunicorn, django-3.0

In my `requirements.txt` I only change from `django==2.2.17` to `django==3.0` (or 3.1.4)
and the `gunicorn` webserver starts leaking postgres db connections.
(Every request increases the number of connections when I check the list of clients in pgbouncer.)

I use python 3.7 and redis (via django-redis).

How can I stop the leakage?
Is there any way to limit the number of connections to a server?

**Update**
The leaks also happen with `django==2.2.17` if I set `'CONN_MAX_AGE': None`, even if I go directly to postgres, avoiding pgbouncer.